# Solving equation systems over finite fields

Tags: java, math, matrix, linear-algebra

I need to invert a quite large (n > 1000) equation system in a finite field (modulo 2^32-5 to be precise). Are there any libraries that can do this efficiently? Preferrably in Java but C is alright (we already have some JNI-bindings).

Comment: Perhaps you want to check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992638/java-inverse-matrix-calculation

Comment: Thanks, but that discusssion is not covering finite fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for [fflas-ffpack](http://linalg.org/projects/fflas-ffpack), it's a C++ Library, the developers are super-friendly and the project is constantly updated.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into that but I can't find any documentation. Do you know if there's any?

Comment: You are right, it should be in their website but it's a stud. Just drop them an email, hopefully they will also put something online. And of course, good luck with your system :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are some linear algebra routines in this [library](http://jscience.org/).