# Inverse of a matrix in java

Tags: java, matrix, sparse-matrix

I would like to calculate an inverse of matrix in java. Are there any already existing packages which calculate inverse of matrix. I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992638/java-inverse-matrix-calculation), but the answers in the questions are not so strongly recommending to use anyof the packages. Even i could not follow the method they are using. I have a large matrix of 10000s of rows and columns. I would
like to calculate inverse of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should give a shot to [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/)

The documentation presents an inverse function for matrices
http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/

Seeing the size of your matrix though, You WILL have to factorize it first .

Comment: I believe jama is discontinued, last release was on 2005-07-13

Comment: Yep, saw it too. I didn't know about Apache lib. Thanks for letting us know

Answer (score 3):

Apache Commons Math have support for [linear algebra](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/linear.html)

Answer (score 1):

The [la4j](http://la4j.org) (Linear Algebra for Java) library supports matrix inversion. Here is the short example:

```
Matrix a = new Basic2DMatrix(new double[][]{
   { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 },
   { 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 },
   { 7.0, 8.0. 9.0 }
});

Matrix b = a.invert(Matrices.DEFAULT_INVERTOR); // uses Gaussian Elimination
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a example in github used Linear Algebra for Java

```
Matrix a =                                               
             factory.createMatrix(new RandomMatrixSource(SIZE,SIZE));
MatrixInverter inverter = a.withInverter(LinearAlgebra.GAUSS_JORDAN);
         Matrix e = inverter.inverse(factory);
```